# Angular/PrimeNG table cell content rendering over frozen columns on scroll

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

Angular: 16.1.0
PrimeNG: 16.0.0

I have some other PrimeNG components in the body of a column, namely a p-inputSwitch.  The first two columns, a checkbox and the row data name, are frozen.  When I resize my window and scroll to the right, the inputSwitch renders on top of the frozen column.

[Example of the issue I am experiencing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chVsq.png)

I noticed if I set the z index for the frozen columns and the p-input switch, it resolved the problem as shown in the included image. Just want to check that there is no better strategy to handle this issue.  It seems like it doesn't affect any text cell contents, I saw the text-overflow inherits clip.  I attempted to set the overflow to hidden but it was ineffective.